# Safely and Asynchronously Interrupt an Infinite-Loop Python Script started by a BASH script via SSH

Tags: python, bash, ssh

**My Setup:**

I have a Python script that I'd like to run on a remote host. I'm running a BASH script on my local machine that SSH's into my remote server, runs yet another BASH script, which then kicks off the Python script:

`Local BASH script --> SSH --> Remote BASH script --> Remote Python script`

The Python script configures a device (a DAQ) connected to the remote server and starts a `while(True)` loop of sampling and signal generation. When developing this script *locally*, I had relied on using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception to interrupt the infinite loop and (most importantly) *safely close the device sessions*.

After exiting the Python script, I have my BASH script do a few additional chores while still SSH'd into the remote server.

Examples of my various scripts...

local-script.sh:

```
ssh user@remotehost "remote-script.sh"
```

remote-script.sh:

```
python3 infinite-loop.py
```

infinite-loop.py:

```py
while(true): 
   # do stuff...
```

---

**My Issue(s):**

Now that I've migrated this script to my remote server and am running it via SSH, I can no longer use the `KeyboardInterrupt` to safely exit my Python script. In fact, when I do, I'll notice that the device that was being controlled by the Python script is *still running* (the output signals from my DAQ are changing as though the Python script is still running), and when I manually SSH back into the remote server, I can find the persisting Python script process and must kill it from there (otherwise I get two instances of the Python script running on top of one another if I run the script again). This leads me to believe that I'm actually exiting my <del>remote-side BASH script</del> SSH session that was kicked off by my local script and leaving my remote BASH *and* Python scripts off wandering on their own... (updated, following investigation outlined in the **Edit 1** section)

In summary, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while in the remote Python script results in:

```
Remote Python Script = Still Running
Remote BASH Script   = Still Running
Remote SSH Session   = Closed
Local BASH Script    = Active ([Ctrl]+[C] lands me here)
```

---

**My Ask:**

How can I asynchronously interrupt (but not fully exit) a Python script that was kicked off over an SSH session via a BASH script? *Bonus points* if we can work within my `BASH --> SSH --> BASH --> Python` framework... whack as it may be. If we can do it with as few extra pip modules installed on top, you just might become my favorite person!

---

**Edit 1:**

Per @dan's recommendation, I started exploring `trap` statements in BASH scripts. I have yet to be successful in implementing this, but as a way to test its effectiveness, I decided to monitor process list at different stages of execution... It seems that, once started, I can see my SSH session, my remote BASH script, and its subsequent remote Python script start up processes. But, when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit, I'm kicked back into the top-level "Local" BASH script and, when I check the process list of my remote server, I see *both* the process for my remote BASH script *and* my remote Python script still running... so my Remote BASH script is not stopping... I'm, in fact, ONLY ending my SSH session...

Comment: Try adding `trap 'kill -- -$$' 0` to the remote bash script which launches python. This kills all processes in the process group of the remote script, when it exits or is interrupted.

Comment: Thanks @dan! I'm not entirely clear where that goes...? It seems like it'd be directly after the `python3 myscript.py` call, but that didn't seem to work...the python process is still persisting...

Comment: There are a bunch of user signals that you can trigger with `kill` and intercept in your Python script, like `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`.

Comment: @TimRoberts (and @dan), it seems like the big problem is not that the remote BASH script isn't closing my remote Python script, but that `[Ctrl]+[C]` is closing the SSH session that my Local BASH script used to tickle things on the remote server... that is to say, I don't think that the problem lies in the Remote BASH script needing to `trap` things, but somewhere in the closing of the SSH session... any tips there?

Comment: Suggesting to explore `pkill` command. To send interrupt through `ssh` to your "Remote Python Script"

Comment: You can also make sure your bash script tries to read from stdin; anything that makes it notice when stdin dies will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

In combining the suggestions from the comments (and lots of help from a buddy), I've got something that works for me:

---

**Solution 1:**

In summary, I made my remote BASH script record its Group Process ID (GPID; that which is also assigned to the Python script that is spawned by the remote BASH script) to a file, and then had the local BASH script read that file to then kill the group process remotely.

Now my scripts look like:

local-script.sh

```
ssh user@remotehost "remote-script.sh"
remotegpid=`ssh user@ip "cat gpid_file"`
ssh user@ip "kill -SIGTERM -- -$remotegpid && rm gpid_file"
# ^ After the SSH closes, this goes back in to grab the GPID from the file and then kills it
```

remote-script.sh

```
ps -o pgid= $$ | xargs > ~/Desktop/gpid_file 
# ^ This gets the BASH script's GPID and writes it to a file without whitespace
python3 infinite-loop.py
```

infinite-loop.py (unchanged)

```
while(true): 
   # do stuff...
```

This solves only most of the problem, since, originally I had set out to be able to do things in my Python script *after* it was interrupted and before exiting into my BASH scripts, but it turned out I had a bigger problem to catch (what with the scripts continuing to run even after closing my SSH session)...

Comment: Think about using systemd services instead of this kind of hack. (systemd supports user services; there's a flag that needs to be set to let them keep running when the named user isn't logged in, but that's an easy toggle to flip).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the feedback! I'll look into it, but based on your phrasing it sounds like your solution would do the opposite of what I'm trying to solve: My problem is that the remote scripts continue to run _in spite of_ the fact that I've exited the SSH session, which is causing issues... (correct me if I'm not understanding you)

Comment: Gotcha. If your goal is for the program to end when the SSH session exits, the suggestion in my comment on the question holds; poll stdin from your Python code, and when the connection is gone that attempt will result in a SIGPIPE.